# How handle the throw error with simple way in node.js express

Tags: node.js, error-handling, middleware

Below (source code:1) is working well, But I want to make become more simple.

I don't want to write a code to call 'catchAsyncErrors' in each time I create a method.

Source code : 1

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const usersRouter = express.Router();
const port = 3000;

const users = [
  // { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' },
  // { id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe' },
];

const getList = () => {
  if (users.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('No users found');
  }
  return users.map(user => ({ id: user.id, name: user.name }));
};

const catchAsyncErrors = fn => (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
};

app.use(express.json());


usersRouter.get('/', catchAsyncErrors (async (req, res) => {
  const list = getList();
  res.status(200).json(list);
}));

usersRouter.post('/', catchAsyncErrors (async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  if (!name) {
    throw new Error('Name is required');
  }
  const id = users.length + 1;
  users.push({ id, name });
  res.status(201).json({ id, name });
}));

app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  //console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({ error: err.message });
});

module.exports = app;
```

But using catchAsyncErrors as midleware on the route (source code:2), It make the application hang

Source code : 2

```
const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const usersRouter = express.Router();
    const port = 3000;
    
    const users = [
      // { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' },
      // { id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe' },
    ];
    
    const getList = () => {
      if (users.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('No users found');
      }
      return users.map(user => ({ id: user.id, name: user.name }));
    };
    
    const catchAsyncErrors = fn => (req, res, next) => {
      Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
    };
    
    app.use(express.json());

    usersRouter.use(catchAsyncErrors);
   
    usersRouter.get('/', async (req, res) => {
      const list = getList();
      res.status(200).json(list);
    });
    
    usersRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => {
      const { name } = req.body;
      if (!name) {
        throw new Error('Name is required');
      }
      const id = users.length + 1;
      users.push({ id, name });
      res.status(201).json({ id, name });
    });
    
    app.use('/users', usersRouter);
    
    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
      //console.error(err.stack);
      res.status(err.status || 500).json({ error: err.message });
    });
    
    module.exports = app;
```

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Source code 2, you are calling catchAsyncErrors middleware on usersRouter, but it should be called on each individual route handler instead. You can achieve this by modifying the catchAsyncErrors function to return a new function that wraps the original route handler function:

```
const catchAsyncErrors = fn => (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
};

usersRouter.get('/', catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res) => {
  const list = getList();
  res.status(200).json(list);
}));

usersRouter.post('/', catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  if (!name) {
    throw new Error('Name is required');
  }
  const id = users.length + 1;
  users.push({ id, name });
  res.status(201).json({ id, name });
}));
```

This way, the catchAsyncErrors middleware is applied to each route handler, without needing to explicitly call it on each one.
I hope this was helpful :)